# Access server machine from an Android device using IP address

Tags: browser, android

Here is a totally wierd scenario that I cannot find solutions anywhere.
Purpose: testing a website using an Android device's browser both connected to the same WIFI.
Results:
- Other PCs can connect without problem to that server machine using an IP address which is 192.168.1.9 on port 80.
- Only the Android machine (IP 192.168.1.199) cannot connect to the server (also using an IP address).

I have tried everything, every resource found on the Net but no luck.

------- EDIT ---------
The wierd part is that other machines on the same Wireless connection can connect without a problem, only the Android device doesn't. I don't use domain name, only a bare IP address.

I also tried using a tracerout app on my Android phone and it can actually trace the server machine using the IP address.

Please help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Oneplus 2 can connect to 192.168 range but Oneplus5 cannot. same Wifi access point, no specific restrictions on the router.

Comment: Does this persist when viewing as desktop?  Or try spoofing user-agent?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw out a guess and say that your router isolates wireless clients from the network.  This means anything connecting via wifi will have internet, but not know anything about the local network.  So there's 2 things you can try to narrow this down:

1. Look through your router settings and turn off "AP Isolation" or something to that effect (see your router manual)
2. Forward a port to your webserver and try to access it via android using your external IP.  Depending on your ISP, you may have to use a non-standard port if they block port 80.

Comment: 1) The wierd part is that other machines on the same Wireless connection can connect without a problem, only the Android device doesn't, so I think AP Isolation shouldnt be the culprit.
2) isn't there anyway I can do it using a LAN IP instead of the router's public IP ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you updated the server DNS in your android mobile and in the server for the checking your website via your android mobile and change the port 80 and use some ports like a random port your system not using, check it locally that your site is working. At last check your system has the active connection to your mobile using the ping.If you found this as an answer tell it in comment.

Comment: I'm using an Ip address, not domain name so, DNS may not be relavant. My Android can connect to other machines and so as other machines.
I will test the ping stuff and post it back here.